# Rewrite javascript variable value on button click

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, I have been working with Java for some time, I made a simple game and i found out it could be a lot better in JS. So I started learning and now I am facing a problem:
When I press a button to increase an int variable it does nothing.
Here is my code:

```
  <script>

    var a=5;

     void function increaseA(){
      a+=1;
     }

    document.write("Value of A is"+a+"<br>");

</script>

   <button onclick="increaseA()" >Increase A</button>
```

the button should actually increase variable a and of course the contain in document.write should change.

Can you help me please?

Comment: There's no `void` in Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `void` for a function like the one you have there. Also, the script is executed without the function being called - so the variable isn't changed at the the time `document.write()` was called. Change it to

```
var a=5;
function increaseA(){
    a+=1;
    console.log("Value of A is"+a+"<br>");
}
```

to get it working.

Also note that `document.write()` will override your entire page, so use `console.log()` instead, or change another div's content to the desired output..

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'void', there is no return type for javascript function definition.

I suggest you to go through some tutorials for basic syntax first.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some pieces.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var a=5;                     
 function increaseA(){
  a+=1;
  document.getElementById('value_of_a').innerHTML = a;
 }
 document.write("Value of A is"+a);
</script>
<button onclick="increaseA()">Increase A</button>
<div id="value_of_a"></div>
```

Comment: Here some tips: script type is important, no void function, update view in your js function, add a div to write into

Comment: Using a document write to update the view would remove the button